# How to debug unit test with MonoDevelop?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, nunit, monodevelop

I have MonoDevelop 2.4.2 on OSX. I have a failing unit test that I would like to debug. Is there a way to do it? I found a [reference](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monodevelop-list/2009-July/010039.html) on MonoDevelop mailing list but my version  does not have mentioned option.

Am I missing something?

Comment: BTW, is there a reason to stay on 2.4.* while 3.* is available? http://monodevelop.com/Download

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to debug a unit test library by right-clicking my "unit test project" in the "Solution Explorer" and choosing "Debug Item".

I'm running the Windows version of MonoDevelop, but the same option is available on Linux and OSX versions.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu version too.  I'd assume it would work on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX monodevelop 3.0.4 this is now: Right click on unit test -> run with -> "Mono soft debugger".

You can add breakpoints using the 'run' menu too, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Xamarin Studio Community. @Kedde's answer does not work for the NUnit test in this version of the IDE. I created a Console project that runs unit tests. I am able to debug by stepping into the console methods.